# Why would deleting a Qt (QSslSocket) object cause a crash

Tags: c++, qt

I am really stumped and hoping somebody out there knows something about my problem.

I have a *very* simple SSL client and server. The connection is fine. Communication is fine. The problem arises when the client disconnects from the server. This fires a signal on the server which is handled in the SLOT `error_handler(QAbstractSocket::SocketError in_error)`. In that function is where the `sslSocket` object has to be deleted, I would imagine.

However doing this causes the server to seg fault. I don’t understand what’s going on. I expected this to be really straightforward but apparently I am missing some Qt (or other) concept.

Can anybody help out?

Essential server code:

```
void SSLServer::incomingConnection(int sd)
{
    sslSocket = new SSLSocket(this);
    if( sslSocket->setSocketDescriptor(sd))
    {
        QFile sslkeyfile(privKey_);
        sslSocket->setPrivateKey(QSslKey(sslkeyfile.readAll(),QSsl::Rsa));

        QFile cliCertFile(serverCert_);
        sslSocket->setLocalCertificate(QSslCertificate(cliCertFile.readAll()));

        QFile certFile(caCert_);
        sslSocket->addCaCertificate(QSslCertificate(certFile.readAll()));

        sslSocket->setPeerVerifyMode(QSslSocket::VerifyPeer);
        sslSocket->setProtocol(QSsl::SslV3);

        connect(sslSocket, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)),
                this, SLOT(error_handler(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));
        connect(sslSocket, SIGNAL(sslErrors(QList<QSslError>)),
                this, SLOT(ssl_error_handler(QList<QSslError>)));
        connect(sslSocket, SIGNAL(encrypted()), this,
                SLOT(ready()));
        connect(sslSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this,
                SLOT(read_data_from_client()));

        sslSocket->startServerEncryption();
        if(!sslSocket->waitForEncrypted())
        {
            qDebug() << "failed to perform SSL handshake with client";
            return;
        }
    }

}

void SSLServer::read_data_from_client()
{
    QByteArray qstrbytes = sslSocket->readAll();
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << qstrbytes;
}

void SSLServer::ready()
{
    QSslCertificate clientCert = sslSocket->peerCertificate();
    qDebug() << clientCert.isValid();
}

void SSLServer::error_handler(QAbstractSocket::SocketError in_error)
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << in_error;
    if(in_error == QAbstractSocket::RemoteHostClosedError)
    {
        delete sslSocket; //// line causes crash !!!!!!
    }
}
```

Comment: You're deleting the object that is making the call to the error handler. That can't be good.

Comment: Am I?? The error handler is a member of 'this' which is SSLServer object. That's not what I am trying to delete. sslSocket object is what I am trying to delete. It comes and goes with connections. SSLServer object is there for the duration of the program. Did I misunderstand something in what you are saying? Thanks.

Comment: You connected `sslSocket`'s signal to that slot. The emitter is the one who calls the slot (for direct connections anyway). i.e. once your slot finishes, code flows back to somewhere in sslSocket's code, with a deleted `this`. That's pretty bad.

Comment: Ah, I think that makes sense. Thanks. I'm going to modify my code accordingly and see where that gets me. Let you if I discover something useful.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`QObject::deleteLater()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html#deleteLater) instead of `delete` since [`QSslSocket`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtnetwork/qsslsocket.html) inherits [`QObject`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html). You may still receive messages on the socket which is causing the crash when you just `delete` the object.

```
sslSocket->deleteLater();
```

When you call `deleteLater()`, Qt automatically disconnects all slots and signals and calls the object destructor after there are no pending events being delivered to the object. See [`QObject::~QObject()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html#dtor.QObject) for more information.

Comment: OK, I get that part. Thanks to everybody for driving the point home. No more crashing now that I am using deleteLater. Only part that's bothering me is I don't really know whether the object ever gets deleted with deleteLater(). Do i understand that correctly? It just puts the object on a queue for deletion, but if the object is being referenced then it won't get deleted. I guess the point is there might be references to that object which I may not have accounted for when i mean for the object to go away, in which case the object never gets deleted. Thus I have a memory leak.

Comment: DeleteLater() is safe specially important when using multithread environments, since one thread delete some object then another thread send signal/messages to deleted object( unexpected senario, may work or not according to Qtframework validation and all).

Comment: @user2722568 Please see my updated answer. It explains how `deleteLater()` automatically disconnects all slots and signals and eventually calls the object destructor.

Answer (score 2):

If you think how a QObject class such as SSLSocket class may be written, it could be something like this:-

```
class SSLSocket : public QObject
{        
   signals:
        void sslErrors(QList<QSslError>);

     void SomeFunction()
     {
        // something went wrong, emit error
        emit sslErrors(errorList);

        Cleanup(); // If a slot connected to sslErrors deleted this, what happens now?!
     }
}
```

When the signal sslErrors is triggered, your slot function is called. As you can see, after emitting the signal, the class may have more work to do. If you immediately delete the object in your slot, this is going to crash, which is why you should always use deleteLater() for deleting QObject instances in slot functions.

The deleteLater function will ensure that the slot function has finished executing and the call stack restored, so it will be deleted at the appropriate time.

Note that the code above is not actually what SSLSocket does, but just an example.

Answer (score 1):

QSslSocket is a QObject. Never just delete a QObject. For sure don't do this in a slot. Always use deleteLater().

Answer (score 1):

Here's Qt example code using QSslSocket:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/network-securesocketclient-sslclient-cpp.html

As the other posters mentioned, use `deleteLater()`, and the error notification is not the only place to do so.